# Plot a boolean matrix marking only non-zero elements

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of boolean entries, like the following:

```
M=
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0
[5,]    1    0    0
```

I would plot this matrix in the following way. If M[i,j] is equal to 1 then the code marks a point on the plot at point (i,j). Otherwise, if M[i,j] is equal to 0 then the code draws nothing.

Comment: Did you meant `i1 <- which(M !=0, arr.ind = TRUE);
plot(x=i1[,1], y = i1[,2], xlab = 'rowIndex', ylab = 'colIndex')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to get the row/column index - `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` will get that

```
i1 <- which(M !=0, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Then `plot` the 'i1' to mark the points

```
plot(x=i1[,1], y = i1[,2], xlab = 'rowIndex', ylab = 'colIndex', pch = 20, col = 'red')
```

[image]

#### data

```
M <- structure(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 3L))
```